# Monotouch create UIView with UIPickerView and display it as a subView from the bottom

Tags: xamarin.ios, uipickerview

After looking at about every web page on Monotouch and reading McClure’s book, I still cannot figure out how to do this. It sounds like a very simple problem to solve: I have a UITableViewController with a table of values. When the client touches one of the values, I need a new View to be built with a Picker and to be displayed from the bottom of the screen. At the moment, I have a Navigator controller pushing the next view that has the picker, but it seems way too busy, so I need to be able to create a UIView and add a UIPickerView in it and show it from the bottom of the screen. And really I would love to do all of that without the help of the Interface Builder. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3695363/90882) should give you the solution you are after.